# Raspberry Pi 3 B+ BLE Scanning Fails After Upgrade (Using Stretch)

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3, ibeacon

BLE scanning using a known working Python example fails on a brand new Raspberry Pi 3 B+ (metal can CPU) after doing an apt-get update/upgrade. To recreate, using NOOBS 2.8.2, set up the Pi and do apt-get update and upgrade, accepting all the suggested changes. Then use [this sample code](https://github.com/switchdoclabs/iBeacon-Scanner-) to scan for BLE devices. As part of diagnostic, the command:

```
hcitool lescan
```

was used to see if the hci0 device could be opened. This led to the error:

```
hcitool lescan Set scan parameters failed: Input/output error
```

This workaround succeeds around that error:

```
hciconfig hci0 down
hciconfig hci0 up
hcitool lescan
```

But only after the 'hcitool lescan' starts running successfully. It's not clear if we have to actually capture scanned devices in the whitelist for the scan to succeed <s>(goes by too fast to catch and stop)</s>.

The sample code fails on these new system versions:

```
ii  bluez                           5.43-2+rpt2+deb9u2           armhf        Bluetooth tools and daemons
ii  bluez-firmware                  1.2-3+rpt6                   all          Firmware for Bluetooth devices
ii  bluez-hcidump                   5.43-2+rpt2+deb9u2           armhf        Analyses Bluetooth HCI packets
ii  libbluetooth-dev                5.43-2+rpt2+deb9u2           armhf        Development files for using the BlueZ Linux Bluetooth library
ii  libbluetooth3:armhf             5.43-2+rpt2+deb9u2           armhf        Library to use the BlueZ Linux Bluetooth stack
ii  pi-bluetooth                    0.1.8                        all          Raspberry Pi 3 bluetooth
ii  python-bluez                    0.22-1                       armhf        Python wrappers around BlueZ for rapid bluetooth development
```

But works on this system, one upgrade back:

```
ii  bluez                           5.43-2+rpt2+deb9u2           armhf        Bluetooth tools and daemons
ii  bluez-firmware                  1.2-3+rpt5                   all          Firmware for Bluetooth devices
ii  libbluetooth-dev                5.43-2+rpt2+deb9u2           armhf        Development files for using the BlueZ Linux Bluetooth library
ii  libbluetooth3:armhf             5.43-2+rpt2+deb9u2           armhf        Library to use the BlueZ Linux Bluetooth stack
ii  pi-bluetooth                    0.1.7                        all          Raspberry Pi 3 bluetooth
ii  python-bluez                    0.22-1                       armhf        Python wrappers around BlueZ for rapid bluetooth development
```

EDIT: Output from btmon command (new non-working unit):

```
Bluetooth monitor ver 5.43
= Note: Linux version 4.14.52-v7+ (armv7l)                                                                                         0.695265
= Note: Bluetooth subsystem version 2.22                                                                                           0.695276
= New Index: B8:27:EB:A0:39:EC (Primary,UART,hci0)                                                                          [hci0] 0.695279
= Open Index: B8:27:EB:A0:39:EC                                                                                             [hci0] 0.695281
= Index Info: B8:27:EB:A0:39:EC (Broadcom Corporation)                                                                      [hci0] 0.695284
@ RAW Open: python (privileged) version 2.22                                                                       {0x0003} [hci0] 0.695289
@ RAW Open: hcitool (privileged) version 2.22                                                                      {0x0002} [hci0] 0.695291
@ MGMT Open: bluetoothd (privileged) version 1.14                                                                         {0x0001} 0.695294
@ MGMT Open: btmon (privileged) version 1.14                                                                              {0x0004} 0.695367
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 40                                                                                   [hci0] 2.692582
      LE Advertising Report (0x02)
        Num reports: 1
        Event type: Scannable undirected - ADV_SCAN_IND (0x02)
        Address type: Random (0x01)
        Address: 51:46:AD:CA:4C:2F (Resolvable)
        Data length: 28
        16-bit Service UUIDs (complete): 1 entry
          Google (0xfe9f)
        Service Data (UUID 0xfe9f): 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
        RSSI: -84 dBm (0xac)
```

From older, working unit:

```
Bluetooth monitor ver 5.43
= Note: Linux version 4.14.34-v7+ (armv7l)                                                                                         0.396738
= Note: Bluetooth subsystem version 2.22                                                                                           0.396744
= New Index: B8:27:EB:31:E6:62 (Primary,UART,hci0)                                                                          [hci0] 0.396746
= Open Index: B8:27:EB:31:E6:62                                                                                             [hci0] 0.396748
= Index Info: B8:27:EB:31:E6:62 (Broadcom Corporation)                                                                      [hci0] 0.396749
@ RAW Open: python (privileged) version 2.22                                                                       {0x0002} [hci0] 0.396752
@ MGMT Open: bluetoothd (privileged) version 1.14                                                                         {0x0001} 0.396753
@ MGMT Open: btmon (privileged) version 1.14                                                                              {0x0003} 0.396800
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 42                                                                                   [hci0] 0.534168
      LE Advertising Report (0x02)
        Num reports: 1
        Event type: Non connectable undirected - ADV_NONCONN_IND (0x03)
        Address type: Public (0x00)
        Address: 0C:F3:EE:B3:B8:53 (EM Microelectronic)
        Data length: 30
        Flags: 0x06
          LE General Discoverable Mode
          BR/EDR Not Supported
        Company: Apple, Inc. (76)
          Type: iBeacon (2)
          UUID: a6ffa91b-91f4-f2ad-0f4a-6dcf5444232f
          Version: 0.256
          TX power: -76 dB
        RSSI: -70 dBm (0xba)
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "It's not clear if we have to actually capture scanned devices in the whitelist for the scan to succeed (goes by too fast to catch and stop)"?

Comment: Please post the output of "sudo btmon" while trying to scan.

Comment: @davidgyoung sorry for muddying the question. Forget the "goes by too fast part." Is whitelisting now required?

Comment: @emil added btmon output with first scanned packet included.

Answer (score 1):

So your scanning seems to be already active (since it delivers an advertisement packet)? The lescan command first sets the scan parameters and then starts the scan. If there already is an ongoing scan, HCI forbids the set scan parameters command.

Comment: So when you say there is an ongoing scan, is it from this line from the non-working unit: 

`@ RAW Open: hcitool (privileged) version 2.22`

Comment: I guess the scan was started earlier than btmon was started, as btmon didn't catch the "LE Set Scan Enable" command, but surely it runs because HCI deliver advertisement events. Try to shutdown bluetoothd (if that's the one that's scanning).

Comment: Shutting down bluetoothd does not change the behavior. Continuing to try and understand the configuration and the timing of what starts when. After restarting a few times, it can work. Race condition?

Comment: You could try add "btmon > /tmp/btlog" to some boot script, to be sure you catch everything. Then you should see when the scan is started.

Comment: Nice idea, will try and report result.

Comment: same issue here.... was using same python code in pi 3 and older and now stuck with this on pi 3b+. Updates?

Comment: I ran out of time to fix the problem and replaced the unit with an older unit from production stock. So I have to bring up the failing unit separately to try this. Will do as quick as I can and post. Extremely annoying to have an RPi update do this :(

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new file (0755), for example lescan.sh in /home/pi/scripts with following code:

> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> sudo hciconfig hci0 down
> sudo hciconfig hci0 up
> sudo timeout -s INT 1s hcitool lescan
> cd /
> cd home/pi/proPi/
> sudo timeout -s INT 1s python *detectAll.py* (replace with your Phyton script name)
> cd /
> ```

2. `sudo crontab -e` and add the following: `@reboot sleep 60 && sh /home/pi/scripts/lescan.sh`

Answer (score -1):

Currently I <s>fix</s> workaround this by calling a script (found [here](http://federicopfaffendorf.com.ar/hcitool-lescan-timeout/)) before using the python scanner.

I call this script with 1s duration:

```
bash lescan.sh 1s /dev/null
```

Comment: script is unreachable.